# Error ld returned 1 exit status causing file program to not run and pings a threat to the system with antivirus off or on

Tags: c++

Using the following, i get the noted error:

```
/*
Name: <name>
Date: 1/30/2021
Assignment#: Classwork2
Status: Work in progress
------------------------------------
Comments:
This program will find perimeter and area of a rectangle
------------------------------------
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declaration of Variables
    int base;
    int height;
    int perimeter;
    int area;
    
    // Initializing Variables
    base=10;
    height=5;
    
    //Calculation Section
    perimeter=(base + height);
    area=(base*height);
    
    //Display Results
    cout << "The perimeter is " <<perimeter << endl;
    cout << "The area is " <<area << endl;
    
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0; 
    
} //end of main()
```

We get this error in the box:

---

Failed to execute "C:\Users\name\Documents\jan30\Example2902.exe":
Error 5: Access is denied.

Press any key to continue . . .

No matter what my teacher and i did, this does not run. Other people in the same class using the same program had no issue. We also turned off our antivirus just in case, but the error still occurs. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think that's a matter of the c++ code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste of the build error output (copy-pasted as text).

Comment: Also please take some time to take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You seem to have two different issues, please ask about *one only*. And considering the first issue ("ld returned 1...") you shouldn't even be able to get the second issue (if the build fail then you have no executable to run).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have an issue with your application clearance. If it sends a ping to your system that there's a virus upon running it then you might either want to check your software or go to your system and downloaded antivirus and allow an exception for the application to run.

Comment: Did all of that, it is definitely an exception, but still doesn't compile & run. I will say that if i remove either perimeter or area as a variable, and their corresponding lines, it works individually. It's only when there are two variables and cout line that it does this.